# why using `XGetInputFocus` causing segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c

---

```
Display *display;
display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Window window;
XGetInputFocus(display, &window, RevertToNone);
```

---

in XGetInputFocus segmentation fault happen; anything wrong ?
(program compile with xlib and don't any problem with compiling)

Comment: You are not testing if an error occurred in the above code. In your real code, do you test for `if(display==NULL)`?

Comment: I test it and is not null

Comment: Are there other differences between this code and your real code?

Comment: post a complete compilable example is your best bet. btw RevertToNone is dangerous, if focus goes to none the desktop is basically hosed. best to never use that.

Comment: doh. also GetInputFocus gets and doesn't set revert to. that's your crash. you need to be providing &revert_to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int revert; XGetInputFocus(display, &window, &revert);` should fix it.